# How to check if Rails 3.2 can connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an easy 'command line/console' way of checking if a Rails app is connecting properly to MySQL?

Unfortunately, I can't get a Rails console to come up.  It complains about:

```
/home/nexargi/www/gi/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib
  /active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined
 local variable or method `abddadhocbkgid' for #<Class:0x000000036427f8> (NameError)
    from /home/nexargi/www/gi/app/models/adhoc_bkg_diners_diet.rb:5:in 
`<class:AdhocBkgDinersDiet>'.
```

The 'abddadhocbkid' is the first attribute of the first table and therefore I am thinking that it is not managing to connect to the mysql database.  I need to find a way of checking if Rails can connect to the mysql database without logging into the rails console.

Here is my model code:

```
class AdhocBkgDinersDiet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :abddadhocbkgid, :abddmealdietid, :abddadultnos, :abddchildnos
  validates_numericality_of :abddadultnos, :abddchildnos, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0

  belongs_to :adhoc_bkg, foreign_key:abddadhocbkgid
 belongs_to :meal_diet, foreign_key: :abddmealdietid
end
```

Comment: Can you display the model code in question?  Based on the error message, the issue is more likely with the code than the DB connection.  Also, have you run the migration(s) for this table?

Comment: @PinnyM I have found the error.  You can see it in the first belongs_to line.  It should read: belongs_to :adhoc_bkg, foreign_key: :abddadhocbkgid.  The surprising thing is that it wasn't failing on my dev system but when I moved it into production then it did.  Any way it's resolved now and thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 13):

If you just need to check if your connection is active after it has been established, there is the [`ActiveRecord::Base.connected?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-connected-3F) method.

Comment: When would the connection be active? When I run this in console for a Rails app that has a PostgreSQL DB and `rails server` is running, this still returns false.

Answer (score 6):

You can try connecting directly using console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
)
```

Or if you have a model you can try finding one:

```
SomeModel.first
```